# Is there any way to hide the sensitive information when i click the dynamic link in browser

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I just created a short dynamic link for this url `https://m.example.com/invitation?gameid=1234&referrer=555`.
It  is working fine, but when i click the `shortlink` in browser it is directing to my page but it is showing all the `sensitive information` like `gameId` and `referrer` in browser address bar. I don't want to show that.
Is there any way to show short link even when i click the shortlink in browser also or anyway to hide the sensitive information.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the answer is no, but why do you want to do this? It adds zero security to do this. Is this information truly secret? What you can do is on your server issue a token that is either this information but encrypted or the token is stored in the database and can be used to look up the information

Comment: Maybe use Hashing of params?

Comment: You can use post method to add parameters in url. Http methods in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Dynamic Links do not provide mechanism to hide link data from person who have access to the link. In addition to exposing the link content in browser address bar (as you already found out), any person can get link details by going to link debug page https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug . Append `?d=1` or `&d=1` to the link to get here.

If you need to hide information, you can consider encrypting the information, like `https://m.example.com/invitation?encrypted_data=<base64 data here>`

Another option is to store data in database and having only data identifier in your link, like `https://m.example.com/invitation?data_id=<identifier>`

If you think your use case is important or widely used, feel free to open Firebase support ticket. We always open to feature requests and suggestions how to improve our product.